Do objects complements always follow after transitive verbs?
I know this might sounds too detailed because transitive verbs are followed by direct objects, which are followed by object complements (of course only when the object complements are necessary for the sentences). So by transitive property, I can infer that object complements always follow transitive verbs but I want to find out some official sources to substantiate my thought. So far only 1 website (Langeek) say it but I am not sure yet because at least in my opinion, it is not a big website. So can anyone tell me if object complements ALWAYS follow transitive verbs? If so, can you provide any source/ link? Thanks

Not always but only when they are necessary. The horse kicked the boy. (No OC) His success has made him haughty. (OC follows the tr.verb). Does this solve your problem?

Not always. The yellow she painted the room reminded her of her grandparents kitchen.

Similarly, you sometimes get other variations on SVO order with transitive verbs, most notably with questions, exclamations, conditionals/counterfactuals, and in poetry/song, but also perhaps with other forms (not sure if e.g. locative inversion would be relevant, but maybe such a locative could be an object complement). "What colour did he paint the room?" "Oh such colours he painted the room!" or (old-fashioned) "Many colours did he paint the room." Is there some specific case you're worried about?

This is just a question about word order, right?

@PaulTanenbaum "The yellow" in your example is not an object complement!

Your question is very unclear! Are you asking whether OCs can come before a verb? Are you asking whether OCs can occur after an intransitive verb? Are you asking whether transitive verbs are always followed by an OC? etc etc etc

Helms too they chose.

@user405662 The question already acknowledges "only when necessary" in the parenthetical in the first sentence.

@Araucaria-Him, I'd say that that's debatable. It could follow an exchange like this: "She painted the room yellow."   "Wait, she painted the room what yellow?" But, if you're not convinced, then my example could always be replaced by something like Yellow you painted the room? Really? Yellow?

@PaulTanenbaum I completely agree that an 'object complement' can precede the subject of a clause. It's just that within your chosen example, "she painted the room __" ,is a relative clause modifying the noun "yellow". The noun yellow is not a preposed complement of the verb paint there. :)

@Barmar Of course they do but they're not sure and needed clarification.

@user405662 Thanks. But I mean in the case where the OC is present, does OC always follow tr.V?

@QuốcAnhPhạm I think yes. But I should point out that modern grammars differ from traditional ones in various respects. I don't know if that's the case here as well. But as per traditional grammars, OC always follows verbs.

@user405662 thanks
